# Angular 8 Http get request with no cache

Tags: angular, typescript, http-headers, cache-control

A get request in my angular application
is able to fetch the data but that request is being stored in cache
and whenever i trigger other page and return back to that page
i see nothing the get request is getting triggered but this is what the response in network tab

```
Request URL: example.com
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 301  (from disk cache)
Remote Address: 104.27.136.237:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

this is what i'm getting
i just want to trigger the http get  or force that call and fetch objects and display them

here is my code part

```
constructor(private http:HttpClient,public dialog: MatDialog){
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'API-KEY': localStorage.getItem("key"),

      })
    }
    this.back =this.backend + localStorage.company_domain
    this.backenddata=this.http.get(this.back,httpOptions).subscribe(
      backenddata=>{
    let ok=backenddata["results"];
    console.log(ok);
}}
```

k

```
Note:By refreshing i'm able to fetch the data but while changing from one page to another page using angular route i'm seeing that 301 response in the network tab
Note:I Have already tried HttpInterceptors still had no luck with that 
Note:  Tried <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />  
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

is there any better option to trigger requests without getting interfered by cache

Comment: Can you create a reproduce this in stackblitz.com?

Answer (score 3):

From the client side, if you change the URL every time you make the get request by appending a new query param, the browser won't cache it.  We can add a cache bust query param with a value of the current time in miliseconds.

This is not very elegant, but it could help.

```js
constructor(private http:HttpClient,public dialog: MatDialog){
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'API-KEY': localStorage.getItem("key"),

      })
    }
    // the new Date().getTime() will add the current time in miliseconds to the end
    this.back = `${this.backend}${localStorage.company_domain}?cache_bust=${new Date().getTime()}`
    this.backenddata=this.http.get(this.back,httpOptions).subscribe(
      backenddata=>{
    let ok=backenddata["results"];
    console.log(ok);
}}
```

The better way would be to solve it on the client side by setting proper cache control headers.  How to do that depends on your server technology.